# Consume Scoped Service From Singleton

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

While consuming a scoped from singleton I am not getting any error 
According to below article, i should get an error as soon as I start my service:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/

Dependency Registered :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger, AppLogs>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICacheFactory>(x =>
            {
                string cacheConnectionString = "xyz";
                return new CacheFactory(cacheConnectionString, x.GetService<ILogger>());
            });
```

Consumed:

```
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ICacheFactory cacheProvider;
        public Function1(ICacheFactory cacheProvider) {
            this.cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        }


        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {


            var result = await this.cacheProvider.GetResultsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>("abc").ConfigureAwait(false);}
}
```

When does a scoped injected in a singleton give an issue?

Comment: Learn about the concept of [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Answer (score 1):

To get an error when using scoped services in singleton instances you must set the ValidateScopes option to true when building the service provider e.g.

```cs
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
```

The validation is somewhat expensive so you can change it to only validate when you are developing like this:

```cs
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: Debugger.IsAttached);
```

[Documentation on BuildServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider)

Comment: @Rosco..i tried it but still no issues...Is there any difference in dependency resolution in function apps vs .net core web API?

Comment: You are using a factory method to create ICacheFactory so maybe the DI system cannot understand that you are using a scoped service in a singleton. The docs say it runs checks on startup which sounds like it looks at registered services and probably doesn't run factory methods to see which services are requested. You could create a test singleton with a scoped dependency and see if it throws a validation error.